# How to return the date part form a timestamp in firestore react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So I am calling my firestore database and trying to return the date part from a timestamp but it is returning the wrong year.

```
<text>{new Date(data.value * 1000).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')}</text>
```

I am aware the 1000 is to with seconds but without it returns invalid date.

[image]

```
getjobs = async () => {

        try {

           const unsubscribe = await firebase.firestore().collection("jobs")
               .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

                    var _jobs = [];
                    querySnapshot.forEach( (doc)=> {
                        const job = doc.data();
                        if(job.company === this.state.user.company){
                            _jobs.push({ ...job, id: doc.id });
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('---------state',this.state);
                    this.setState({
                        jobs: _jobs,
                    })
                });
                this.setState({
                    unsubscribe
                })

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error cant get jobs', e);
        }
    }
```

List item

```
Item = (data, index) => {
  return (
      <ListItem thumbnail key={index} style={styles.listItem}>
        
          <Body>
              <Text>Job Number: {data.jobnumber}</Text>
              <Text note numberOfLines={1}>Trade: {data.trade}</Text>
              <Text note numberOfLines={1}>PostCode: {data.postcode}</Text>
              <Text note numberOfLines={1}>Date: {new Date(data.value * 1000).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')}</Text>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <FontAwesome5 name="chevron-right" size={22} color="#f53025" />
          </Right>
           
      </ListItem>

  );
```

}

Comment: What is the actual year that you wish to retrieve and what do you get without 1000?

Comment: The date I wish to receive is what ever date is in the firestore database which is inputted by users. Without the 1000 I get invalid date.

Please see edit.

Comment: I tried it with 1000 and without 1000, and it returns **invalid date** in both cases. However, when I removed 'at' from date.value it worked perfectly fine. May I know how you are setting that date?

Comment: What do you mean by removing 'at'?

Comment: I meant, when I passed the value shown in the image to **Date** object like so: `new Date('May 6, 2021 at 1:46:52 PM UTC+1')`, it returned invalid date, but this worked absolutely fine: `new Date('May 6, 2021 1:46:52 PM UTC+1')`

Comment: How did you remove the 'at' sorry iv only just realised what you meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220028/discussion-between-tushar-and-ding0).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now, we have no idea how `data` gets its value.

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize one of my documents within my collection didn't have a date field and that's why it was giving me an error.

```
{data.value.toDate().toLocaleDateString('en-GB')}
```